# Why aren't Commit All and Push commands available in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019

Using VS 2019 community with the latest update..=

I have a remote repository on GitHub and the local repository on my computer. It used to work OK - meaning committing and pushing.
I have not used it for a while.
Now all I can see is Commit All, Stash all and Stash all and keep staged. I don't have the option to Commit All and Push.

When I open the GitHub tab it shows the following error (see image1)

Can't find GitHub URL for repository. Repository must have a remote called "origin" defined in order to locate their GitHub URL.

This is what I have done so far

Add GitHub as an account to Visual studio. I see now two tabs on Git and one GitHub.

Delete one of the remotes that are not in used from Manage remotes

What I can do now is - On the Git tab, Commit all, then go to Git menu which now shows an option to Push as well as other options that were not there. See image 2 of the Git menu.

What changes I need to do and to what, so I can get to Commit all and Push in the github tab?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please be aware that git and GitHub are not the same thing

Comment: I find the question a bit confusing.
Now all I can see is Commit All, Stash all and Stash all and keep staged. I don't have the option to Commit All and Push.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is giving you a clue. You need to ensure you have a remote defined named "origin".

Go to the Git menu --> Manage Remotes --> and ensure you have a t least one remote defined with the name "origin"